# Elif Statement See Nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this code i can use clearly other elif statements and doesn't show any error to me but in last point else or another elif which has off range to my function it doesn't see any codes into it. Print or new caller, nothing run there. How can i fix this? I tried to fix it by using while or another elif statement instead of else. But it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: No value is ever smaller than 1 and bigger than 10

Comment: The elif condition `elif a<1 and a>10` will never execute.

Comment: In future, please post code as text in a codeblock (type \`\`\`code\`\`\`), not as an image. The problem is that you use the `and` keyword instead of `or`, which checks whether a number is both bigger than 10 **and** less than 1, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

you can not have a number be smaller than 1 and bigger than 10 at the same time. you could do this

```
elif a<1:
  function()
elif a>10:
  otherfunction()
```

Comment: Or instead of that code, he could also just use "or" instead of "and"